# Why doesn't pseudo-random function take seed directly as an argument?

Tags: c, random

When generating random numbers, people first call `srand(int seed)`to generate the seed, then call `rand(void)`.

My question is why not directly use one single function as `rand(int seed)`.

The C standard has a quote which I don't understand, saying

> The implementation shall behave as if no library function calls the srand     function.

I'm not sure if it has something to do with this statement.

The standard also gives an example implementation, which I don't understand the reason of using a static variable:

```
static unsigned long int next = 1;
int rand(void) // RAND_MAX assumed to be 32767
{
    next = next * 1103515245 + 12345;
    return (unsigned int)(next/65536) % 32768;
}
void srand(unsigned int seed)
{
    next = seed;
}
```

Comment: The part about the library not calling `srand()` (and `rand()` itself) is probably intended to ensure repeatability of the sequence generated by `rand()`.

Comment: Man pages exist to be read before using the functions they describe. Alternatively you can read a C book which describes how they are intended to use. Once read, itr will be very clear why your question proposal is - well - a bad idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not supposed to call `srand` everytime you call `rand`. In fact, it is a very bad idea, since the same seed gives you the same sequence everytime : you'd end up generating a constant value.

`srand` should be called when you want to start generating a new sequence of random values. In the typical case, it's once, at the beginning of the program.

From then on, every call to `rand` will return the next number in the sequence. That's why there's a static variable here : so that `rand` can pick up where it previously left and generate the next number.